# Error while retrieving information from the server RPC:s-7:AEC-0

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I Am developing In app purchases in my App by following [[TUT] Simple InApp Billing / Payment V3](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/)

Is is working for me and payment is successful

1. SKU `android.test.purchased`

2.Managed Purchase type.

But why It is giving the  "Error while retrieving information from the server RPC:s-7:AEC-0" for

1. SKU "android.test.purchased"
2. consume the purchase.

All I change the code is only one line

`public static final String ITEM_TYPE_INAPP = “subs”;` in place of

`public static final String ITEM_TYPE_INAPP = “inapp”;` in  `IaBHelper.java`

I struck in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

After days of searching I couldn't find a solution, eventually I tried [this](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) library instead and not the one from Google in TrivialDrive and didn't get the error and could make a test purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because you change from product to subscription, but it's **to verify**.

if you read the google developers page : http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

you have the following :

"Test purchases are only supported for in-app products, not for in-app subscriptions."

so before it works, and after your change it's not supported.